# Eclipse dynamic web project has multiple duplicate deployment descriptors

Tags: eclipse

I have an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project that has multiple deployment descriptors (2 extra) that are adversely affecting deployment:

[image]

I do not know how extra came to be, nor how to get rid of them.  There is only 1 web.xml file in the project located in `WebContent/WEB-INF`

How do I eliminate the extra descriptors?

**Edit**

Created a new `Dynamic Web Project` in workspace.  The new project only has 1 deployment descriptor:

[image]

Furthermore, the contents of the `.settings folder`:

[image]

Whereas the `.settings folder` for the project with the extra deployment descriptors:

[image]

Comment: can post screenshot of your web project's folder structure. (navigator view with all nodes expanded)

Comment: @guleryuz That would be difficult - it's a very large project.  Is all that really necessary?

Comment: ok. can you try adding a new web project to your workspace. will you see again three "Deployment Descriptor"s. if not can you compare folder structure and file contents inside .settings folder of both web projects

Comment: @guleryuz  Please see my edit.  The folder structure looks similar.

Comment: @guleryuz  I'm not sure what to tell you, but the two extra deployment descriptors have disappears from my project explorer.  While I don't have any evidence to prove it, the creating of a new project seems to have fixed something within Eclipse.  Again, I don't know that, but it's pretty coincidental!

Comment: :) eclipse has some wonderful hidden features

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and a simple right click on the project and "Refresh" erased the duplicates ones

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this issue by doing the following:
-Clean server
-Run as->Maven build...
-Goals: clean install
-Run (after completion console window should say BUILD SUCCESS.. else fix your errors..)
-Maven -> Update Project

These steps only work if you are using Maven build tool.. but they worked for me as I was facing a similar issue with multiple deployment descriptors, and because of this my server was unable to pick up my coding changes