# eclipse duplicate deployment descriptors with maven webapp

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I get multiple deployment descriptors on every sub package I create within every new webapp project. Why is that, why is there no java source folder by default and do I have to f* around with this or no? Here is what I do:
File->New...->Other->Maven Project->choosing the org.apache.maven.archetypes maven-archetype-webapp as archetype->giving a name for the new artifact->finish
the generated project does not have a java source folder out of the box? if I make one, I get the duplicate deployment descriptors on every sub package within the java source folder. Unfortunately the image upload does not work, so I can't provide screenshots.
What do I do wrong?
I tried to do that: [Eclipse dynamic web project has multiple duplicate deployment descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225499/eclipse-dynamic-web-project-has-multiple-duplicate-deployment-descriptors)
but it is always the same. duplicate deployment descriptors on every package. with clean, update, clean, update, refresh, clean, refresh, update, refresh, clean, ... :\

Comment: Screenshots and knowing what versions you're using would probably be useful.

Comment: as mentioned above, i can not provide screen shots, as stackoverflow is preventing me from uploading them. version wise eclipse is on 4.23.0, the m2e plugin i use for maven does not say what version, only "Latest"

Comment: Same with version 4.28.0, after import of gradle project with wtp plugin active. Advices in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166650/why-deployment-descriptor-archetype-created-web-application-appears-in-every-p did not help, after commenting out display-name tag in web.xml the Deplyment descriptor keeps showing but with "web app" placeholder instead of real name